# Find replace text in multiple files in subdirectories. Exclude some subdirectories

Tags: unix, replace, sed, find

I want to find replace a patter1 into pattern2 only in certain files of my subdirectories. But exclude some subdirectories with replacement. What is wrong with this command?

```
find ./ -type f --exclude-dir='workspace' --exclude-dir='builds' \
    -exec sed -i '' 's/foo/bar/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the option `--exclude-dir` in `man find` (I do in `man grep`, but you can't just borrow other command's options).

Try

```
find . -type f -not -path './workspace*' ...
```

Comment: What went wrong was probably copying your typo `-f` instead of just `f`.